# Line ending issues? Windows > Mac

Tags: newline

I'm unclear if this is a line ending issue or something else.  I'm getting a zipped directory of code from a developer working on windows (using dreamweaver set to CR LF) and trying to manually add that to git.  The files turn up 100% changed unless I set git's core.autocrlf to false but even with that setting I'm getting the files double spaced.  I thought windows was adding \r\n so I tried removing it with both vim (^M):

`:%s/^V^M//g`

and perl:

`perl -pe 's/\r\n|\n|\r/\n/g'   inputfile > outputfile`

What's strange is if I remove new lines (\n) with vim `:%s/\n//g` the file contains no line breaks at all.  If I use vim's `:set list` on the blank lines I'm just getting `$`.  I'm obviously missing something but I would think I'd be able to get the file, remove the windows line breaks, and be able to add to git with it only showing the actual changes.  Any help would be greatly appreciated as the files are really large (LOC) and there are many of them so a manual (copy/paste) doesn't seem like a great option.

Edit: I just confirmed it's "double spaced" on windows (using notepad++) and setting the "line break type" in Mac dreamweaver has no effect.

Answer (score 0):

You need to have the person on Windows change their line break type to "LF (Unix)".

EDIT: In CS5 it is located at: Edit>Preferences>Code Format>Line Break Type